# Generating electricity in space with magnets

Tags: electromagnetism, electricity

Assuming we have a very strong magnet of strength **B** and of uniform mass in space inside a coil of copper wire of turns **N**. Also, assuming that the magnet spins at the centre of the coil with no relative side motion, this would mean that the magnet continuously spin without stopping because there is no collision with the coil or other object, hence no external force applied.

Would this mean that electricity is continuously generated due to this rotation within the coil, assuming the perfect conditions stated?

Answer (score 2):

The current induced in the coil will produce a magnetic field that opposes the spinning magnet.

I like to demonstrate this with a hand cranked generator.  With an open circuit no current flows and it is easy to turn the crank.  Once you hook a small light bulb up to the generator or, even better, short circuit it, it becomes noticeably more difficult to turn the crank.

Comment: Ah yes that's true, Lenz's law would apply in this situation too...

Comment: You can't get something for nothing.